# c# Count up +1 when number is 6

Tags: c#

i'm pretty new and i was wondering when if i press a butten a random number comes on but when that number is 2 there should be another textbox showing how many times it got 2.

**without using if/else or switch**

```
private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       double number2 = 0;
       double When2 = 2;

       Random number = new Random();
       double chose = number.Next(1,7);
       txtnumber.Text = chose.ToString();

       txtnumber2.Text = something...
}
```

**Solution:** (it's not possible with the number 2 but it is with the number 6)

```
  // global var
    int number6 = 0;
    private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

           double When6 = 6;

           Random number = new Random();
           double chose = number.Next(1,7);
           txtnumber.Text = chose.ToString();
           number6 = Convert.toInt32(number6 + (chose/When6));

           txtnumber6.Text = number6.ToString();
    }
```

---

**L.B's note:** *OP's comment at one of the deleted answer*

> it's a pretty anoying task and i just need to do this without the if/ese or switch

Comment: Is this a homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962571/problems-reading-and-writing-to-a-text-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: `txtnumber2.Text = choose == 2 ? (++counter).ToString() : counter.ToString()`

Comment: why the downvote? this question **without if/else** is nice

Comment: when the number is 2 the textbox will do +1 but when it's gone it's back 0 . it has to keep counting

Comment: Just use `? :` and tell the teacher to be more explicit next time. Cheat ftw lol owned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No array, no dictionary, no Linq, no built-in methods like Convert.ToIn32 etc. Only *bit twiddling*

```
Random number = new Random();
int TwosCount = 0;

private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int chose  = number.Next(1, 7);
    TwosCount += ~((chose & 4) >> 2) & ((chose & 2) >> 1) & ~((chose & 1) >> 0);

    txtnumber.Text = chose.ToString();
    txtnumber2.Text = TwosCount.ToString();
}
```

PS: You can remove some unnecessary parentheses and write as:

```
~(chose & 4) >> 2 & (chose & 2) >> 1 & ~(chose & 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

For a small range of random numbers such as this, (Random.Next(1,7) produces numbers from 1 to 6) you can use an array to keep track of how many times a number has come up. Make sure to declare this array inside of your main class, but outside of your button click method. Also, it doesn't look like you need to use floating point numbers for this job, so I've changed all the double variables to integers.

```
int[] numberCount = new int[6];
//if you really want to stay with doubles, then simply change the above line to this:
//double[] numberCount = new double[6];

private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number2 = 0;
    //double When2 = 2;  This line is not needed, so it's been commented out.

    Random number = new Random();
    int chose = number.Next(1,7);
    numberCount[chose - 1]++; // Increment the amount of times we've seen this particular number
    txtnumber.Text = chose.ToString();

    txtnumber2.Text = numberCount[1].ToString(); // Display the amount of times we've seen the number 2
    //Remember, array indexes are 0 based, so index 1 is actually the second number in the array, or number 2.
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Using a Dictionary<bool, int> is more scalable.

Answer (score 2):

We can use this formula to find our index `(Rnd -3)%2`

when we subtract 3 from value, if its 2 or lower, it would get negative results as

1-3=-2 and -2%2=0

2-3=-1 and -1%2=-1

and other numbers results would be 0 or 1.

then we can add calculated value by one to start index from 0, now we have an array with three elements which the first element is number of occurrences of **2**.

```
    private readonly Random _random=new Random();
    private readonly int [] numbers=new int[3];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var number = _random.Next(1,7);
        var chose = number;
        chose -= 3; //mod (2-3)=-1
        chose %= 2;
        chose++;

        numbers[chose]++;

        txtnumber.Text = number.ToString();
        txtNumber2.Text = numbers[0].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ;-)

```
double[] two = { 2 };
int count2 = 0;

private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double chose = number.Next(1, 7);
    txtnumber.Text = chose.ToString();
    count2 = count2 + System.Convert.ToInt32(two.Contains(chose));
    txtnumber2.Text = count2.ToString();
}
```

Comment: this is the best proposed solution so far,it works with both natural and real numbers.doesn't use lots of memory in case of wider random range unlike array or dictionary solutions, I wonder why the rates suggest something else!

Answer (score 0):

```
Random R = new Random();
void RUN()
{
    int N = R.Next(2);
    Action[] A = new Action[2];
    A[0] = new Action(Act1);
    A[1] = new Action(Act2);

    A[N].Invoke();
}

private void Act2()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
}

private void Act1()
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
```

this answer is without if/else/switch